# How to interpret a text: What's the wording for $P(X\in A, Y \in B) $ or $P(X\in A| Y \in B)$?

Tags: probability, soft-question

When can we interpret the text of an exercise as wanting $P(X\in A, Y \in B) $ or $P(X\in A| Y \in B)$? What specific expressions are we supposed to use?

The simplest are *given* for the conditional (ex: what's the prob of $X \in A$ given that $Y\in B$) and *and* for the intersection. However, I've seen many textbooks where this wording is not that clear cut. For example, I've recently read an exercise where the author stated (in words): « The probability of $Y\in B$ is something. Of these, the probability of $X \in A$ is somethingelse». How am I supposed to interpret this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no strict rules governing the wording of such problems. Conditional probabilities are often associated with phrases like *given*, *conditional on*, *among those*, *of those* or *if it is known that*. Thus I would interpret the example sentence you give to mean

$$P(Y\in B) = \text{ something, and } P(X\in A |Y\in B) = \text{ somethingelse.}$$

A professor of mine once said "A lack of clarity of expression points to a lack of clarity in thinking." So if you feel that a certain author is consistently unable to express himself clearly, you should perhaps consider picking up a different book.

Comment: Many thanks 1524 ;)